# 're' field in sa -m command

Tags: linux, monitoring, command-line-interface

Can you tell me the significance of `re` field in `sa -m` command.

```
# sa -m
                                     9053       4.56re       0.08cp     1003k
mjz                                  9000       3.06re       0.08cp      967k
root                                   33       1.50re       0.00cp     3934k
nagios                                 12       0.00re       0.00cp    14159k
test                                    6       0.00re       0.00cp     7695k
sshd                                    2       0.00re       0.00cp    16010k
```

I read some where that it is actual real time the process takes to complete. But I don't think its the case.

Comment: You need to add more information here... On which system? What are you trying to do? Be more concise...

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [this source](http://fossies.org/dox/acct-6.3.5/sa_8c_source.html), "real time" (re) is understood as another name for "elapsed time" or the field acct.ac_etime from raw accounting file (see `man acct`).

I'm not sure what is and what is not included in "elapsed time", but from experience this is simply the time since program execution (if a program does nothing but wait() for 1 second, the ac_etime = 1 second). See [this manual](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/pseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.prftungd/doc/prftungd/use_time_measure_cpu_use.htm) - although it is about `time` command, I think the definition is the same.

The `sa -m` does not print the elapsed time of one process; it takes all the processes run by a user and prints a sum of their elapsed times.